# php-fpm and nginx image and css serving in a multi container setup

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose, docker-swarm

So we are currently working on a 1 webserver multiple PHP-FPM setup in Docker-Compose locally and Docker-Swarm on prod., and we started to feel like the job is done then we run into some issues with php-fpm when we wanted to load some image we got:

> NOTICE: Access to the script '/app/DSDPersonnel/test.jpg' has been denied (see security.limit_extensions)

Then I started googling around and found out it's a php fpm error in `www.conf` or `php-fpm.conf`, so I tried to edit those.

Since we running this setup on docker I tried the following solutions:

- `RUN echo security.limit_extensions = FALSE > /etc/php/fpm/php-fpm.conf` this just completly break the container.
- Tried to pass it as a `fastcgi_param` on nginx `fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "security.limit_extensions = FALSE";` which resulted in:

> ERROR: Passing INI directive through FastCGI: unable to set 'security.limit_extensions'

and then after page loading got the same:

> NOTICE: Access to the script '/app/DSDPersonnel/test.jpg' has been denied (see security.limit_extensions)

- tried to tinkering with `fast_cgi params` without any success.
- tried to insert `include=/etc/php-fpm.d/*.conf` to `php-fpm.conf` then load `ext.conf` which contains `security.limit_extensions = FALSE`

Now I am completely out of ideas. Here is our nginx conf:

```
location /DSDPersonnel {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass dsd-personnel:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Any suggestion is useful but we don't want to move the images from the php container to the nginx because of the multiple container setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Editing www.conf should do the trick I tested it right now on php-fpm 7, uncomment the line

`security.limit_extensions = .php .php3 .php4 .php5`

and add it the .jpg extension
`security.limit_extensions = .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .jpg`

or uncomment it, and remove any extension in your dockerfile (beware of security risk):

`RUN echo "security.limit.extensions =" >> /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`

(be careful of your www.conf location, and the >> that will append to file, instead of completely overwriting it)